# Groovy: Print with different file names

Tags: groovy, soapui

I'm learning groovy language and use SOAP for my tests, also I'm newbie for languages. I just run my load script but I want printout my request and responses via another filename. I can print requests/responses but writes on same file.

Here is my path:

```
def outputPath = "C:/FileName/"

outputPath = outputPath

def folder = new File( outputPath )

if( !folder.exists() ) {
  folder.mkdirs()
}

return outputPath
```

And here is my printout:

```
def request = context.expand( '${Script1#Request}' )
def response = context.expand( '${Script1#Response}' )
def outputPath = context.expand( '${init#result}' )

def requestPath = outputPath + "/Script1_req.xml"
def responsePath = outputPath + "/Script1_res.xml"

def f = new File(requestPath)
f.write(request, "UTF-8")

def f2= new File(responsePath)
f2.write(response, "UTF-8")
```

How can I printout my everyscript with another file name like example script1_req(1-XXXX).xml ?

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Do you mean,  "request and response are being overwrite when the test is run multiple times". So, would you like save them in a unique file?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I tryed write long date to file names but I fail.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation, please try the provided answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to is to have unique value to be appended for the file name.

Chang below two statements

```
def requestPath = outputPath + "/Script1_req.xml"
def responsePath = outputPath + "/Script1_res.xml"
```

To:

```
//Get the date in the given format
​def date = new Date().format('yyyyMMddHHmmss')
def requestPath = "${outputPath}/Script1_req_${date}.xml" as String
def responsePath = "${outputPath}/Script1_res_${date}.xml" as String
```